# Are there neural networks that compute weights dynamically based on geometric attributes of neurons?

Tags: neural-networks, deep-learning, papers

I am interested in exploring neural network architectures where the weights are not stored but are computed dynamically based on certain attributes or "dimensions" of the connected neurons.

For instance, consider a fully connected network where each neuron has three geometric attributes (x, y, z). The weight between two neurons with attributes (x1, y1, z1) and (x2, y2, z2) could be computed using a function like: w = 1/((x2 - x1)^2 + (y2 - y1)^2 + (z2 - z1)^2) (let's call this function 'invsq').

This approach seems like it could potentially reduce the memory requirements for storing weights at the cost of a more complex computation to determine the weights dynamically.

Has there been any research or are there existing neural network architectures that employ a similar method for computing weights? I am open to learning about related or alternative approaches if the exact type of network I'm describing doesn't exist.

I've come across some articles discussing dynamic weight strategies and alternative methods for weight computation in neural networks, but none that specifically address geometric attributes of neurons as a basis for weight computation.

Thank you in advance for any insights or references you can provide!

Comment: It's an interesting idea. One major flaw with the current invsq function is that it is always positive. You need to fix that, but the general idea of a function based on distance between neurons in a reduced dimension space (compared to product of layer sizes) might have some interesting properties, and is trainable via back propagation of gradients provided the distance-related function is differentiable. I don't know if there is any related research, but might look into it to see if this can be answered

Comment: I see your point, however, as far as i know, the problem with NN are the FLOPS, not the memory... memory is getting cheaper at a much faster rate than the scaling of CPU/GPU

Comment: @NeilSlater Appreciate your feedback. The invsq function is a starter idea. I envision a system where each neuron has a unique scale, adjusted during training. Scales could mimic logical gates like NOT (negative scales, making '-1' behave like low power), although OR gates are still in contemplation. This might require a broader network architecture to form multiple circuits. Additionally, the neuron dimensions can remain fixed, and altering the scales could solely drive the learning. Your insights are invaluable as I refine this concept.

Comment: @Alberto Thank you for highlighting the concern regarding FLOPS. The idea of dynamically computing weights aims at exploring alternative architectural and operational paradigms for neural networks, which might have implications beyond memory efficiency. The notion of embedding logical operations within the network through adaptable scales and fixed dimensions could potentially lead to novel mechanisms for neural computation, even if it necessitates more complex calculations. Your input sheds light on an important aspect, and I appreciate the discussion.

Comment: @DeadbeefDevelopment sure, my comment wanted to be just a note... in my experience, I've never heard of something like this, where neurons have properties and not connections, however, "plain" NN are universal approximators, so they can definitely approximate any network that you would be able to build with this new paradigm

Comment: this however doesnt mean that they might not work better (being able to approximate is far from "being better")... might be that this structure induces some properties or regularization that enables generalization easier, or something else

Comment: personally, i don't recall anything like this, apart from low rank dense layers (see https://arxiv.org/pdf/2009.03887.pdf) where there is a scalar product between low rank matrix, that are similar to your "xyz" product